# recursive function, get list of multiples

Tags: python

question : Write a recursive function named get_list_of_multiples(numbers, m) that takes a list of integers and an integer as parameters. This function returns a list of multiples of m in the list in the same order as the given parameter. The function should return an empty list if there are no multiples of m in the list.

hey guys, im having trouble with my code:

```
def get_list_of_multiples(numbers, m):

    if len(numbers) > 1:
        if(numbers[0] % m == 0):
            return [numbers[0]] + get_list_of_multiples(numbers[1:], m)
        return get_list_of_multiples(numbers[1:], m)
    if(numbers[0] % m == 0):
        return [numbers[0]]
    else:
        return []
```

test cases are:

```
print(get_list_of_multiples([2, 3, 5, 6], 2))
print(get_list_of_multiples([9, 5, 15, 11, 23], 3))
print(get_list_of_multiples([], 2))
```

the first two test cases are fine but for the last test case where it is empty it is suppose to return an empty list but it keeps coming up with an error saying list index is out of range. what do i modify in the code to make it work? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to this:

```py
def get_list_of_multiples(numbers, m):

    if len(numbers) > 1:
        if(numbers[0] % m == 0):
            return [numbers[0]] + get_list_of_multiples(numbers[1:], m)
        return get_list_of_multiples(numbers[1:], m)
    elif len(numbers) == 0:
        return []
    elif (numbers[0] % m == 0):
        return [numbers[0]]
    else:    
        return []
```

The reason you get an `IndexError` is because of the line `numbers[0] % m == 0`. If the length of the list is `0`, you still check if the 0th element of the list is divisible by `m`, but if it's an empty list, there is no 0th element.

In the updated code, you first check if the length of the list is `0`, if it is, return an empty list, if not, check if the 0th element is divisible or not.